# What do each of the 5 xml files do when creating a master/detail activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, master-detail

I'm looking at many tutorials on getting to grips with master detail flow in Android studio.  However, not a single tutorial matches what happens when I add a `master/detail` flow `Activity`.

Lets say for example I right click my projects `res/layout` folder and select

> New > Activity > Master/Detail Flow.

Then Lets say I fill the box in as follows and click Finish:

[image]

I get the following `XML` files created inside my `res/layout` folder:

1. activity_people_detail. xml
2. activity_people_list. xml
3. people_detail. xml
4. people_list. xml
5. people_list_content. xml

All the tutorials I have watched have 3 `XML` files and one has the word 'Fragment' in the title.  I'm a bit confused.

I also get 3 java classes and a Dummy content class created which do make sense... sort of to me so I don't need to know about these.

Can somebody explain to me what each `XML` does ?  Rather than pointing me to Android documentation, in simplistic terms would be very helpful.

Comment: "I'm a bit confused" -- your tutorials are old, apparently. Android Studio changes over time. Part of those changes include changing what templates exist and what they generate. "Can somebody explain to me what each xml does ?" -- edit your question and paste in the XML, and perhaps somebody can help. After all, we do not have those files.

Comment: Quite simply, the files that end with `list` would hold a `ListView` (`RecyclerView` now, most likely) so when you click an item in the list it would open up the fragment or activity with details of that item. These are templates to get you started but you obviously can modify, delete, add as needed for your project. You can obviously name them whatever you want that complies with the naming standards. These are just to make it more clear what you would use them for.